# Clearing the contents of SWT-CheckboxTableViewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have implemented as shown below.

[image]

The issue what I am facing is in clearing the contents of CheckboxTableViewer, Right now I am keeping track of the items present in the CheckboxTableViiewer and then removing the 0th element, but this is causing problems when the user moves around the list very swiftly.

```java
list= new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(container, SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.VIRTUAL);
list.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
```

Code for Check Box

```java
table = new Table(container, SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.VIRTUAL);
table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
table.setHeaderVisible(true);
checkboxTableViewer = new CheckboxTableViewer(table);
```

in the listener, I tried to get the table and clear the table but that was not working.

```java
checkboxTableViewer .getTable().clearAll();
```

please let me know how to proceed.

**Updated with Code**

```java
package com.checkagain.importWizards;


public class PageTwo extends WizardPage {
    private Text text1;
    private Composite container;

    org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List single;
    Table table ;
    CheckboxTableViewer checkboxTableViewer;
    List elementList= new ArrayList();



    public PageTwo() {
        super("PageTwo");
        setTitle("PageTwo");
        setDescription("Fake Wizard: PageTwo");
        elementList.add("1"); 
        elementList.add("2");
        elementList.add("3");

        elementList.add("4");
        elementList.add("5");
        elementList.add("6");

    }

    @Override
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
        container.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        layout.numColumns = 2;


        single= new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List(container, SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.VIRTUAL);
        single.add("one");
        single.add("two");

        single.add("three");
        single.add("four");

        single.add("five");
        single.add("six");
        //single.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
        //////Code for Check Box


         table = new Table(container, SWT.CHECK | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.VIRTUAL);
         //table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        checkboxTableViewer = new CheckboxTableViewer(table);

        single.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //additional code added on suggestion
                checkboxTableViewer.setInput(new String[0]);
                checkboxTableViewer.refresh();              

                checkboxTableViewer.add(elementList.get(single.getSelectionIndex()));
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        setControl(container);
        setPageComplete(true);
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return text1.getText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the JFace table viewers you should avoid accessing the underlying Table - the table viewer manages that.

Also you are specifying the `SWT.VIRTUAL` flag - tables behave very differently with this flag it is only useful for large tables.

You can clear the viewer by setting the table viewer input to an empty array using `setInput` or by making your content provider return an empty elements array and calling `refresh` - a simple example:

```java
CheckboxTableViewer checkboxTableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(shell, SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

checkboxTableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
checkboxTableViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());

final List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
input.add("entry 1");
input.add("entry 2");
input.add("entry 3");

checkboxTableViewer.setInput(input);

Button clear = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
clear.setText("Clear");

clear.addListener(SWT.Selection, event ->
  {
    input.clear();

    checkboxTableViewer.refresh();
  });
```

Comment: I have tried using this, but went wrong, 
**checkboxTableViewer .setInput(new ArrayList());** could you please provide a code snippet.

Comment: Even on using **checkboxTableViewer.refresh()**, the data is not getting cleared. If I choose another from the list it is getting appended to the CheckBoxTableViewer.

Comment: You need to provide a proper [mcve] so we can see what you are doing. Something we can actually test.

Comment: Added an example. But I also notice you have specified `SWT.VIRTUAL` - that makes tables behave differently and is only useful for large tables and requires extra code.

Comment: I had update the question, without noticing your answer, Let me try implementing this and will get back. If I am still struggling.

Comment: I have incorporated your suggestions and it works fine for me. Thanks a lot.